# How to load an OpenLayers view into the content area with an AJAX link?

Tags: 7, views, ajax, javascript

I have a link in the side bar that links to a OL view.

I would like to Ajaxify it so the view is loaded into the content area without a page re-load.

I am using the Ajax link example in the [Example](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module and saving the `$output` at `ajax_link_response()` with this code:

```
<?php
...
function ajax_link_response($type = 'ajax') {
  ...
  $view = views_get_view('view-name');
  $view->set_display('display-name');
  $view->exposed_input['myfilter'] = 'filter-value';
  $view->pre_execute();

  // $output = t("This is some content delivered via AJAX");

  $output = $view->render();
  ...
```

This solution works fine for non OL views but fails to load a OL view into the wrapper div. What am I missing?

Gist files:

- [ajax_example.module](https://gist.github.com/4640536)
- [ajax_example.misc.inc](https://gist.github.com/4640494)

Comment: how does the ajax link code look like?

Comment: This might be helpful - http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7

Comment: Response to @MohammedShameem . There are 2 examples, neither one works.

Please take a look at the code at https://gist.github.com/4640494

Comment: @MohammedShameem here is the hook_menu implementation, https://gist.github.com/4640536

Comment: that looks fine to me. if you have devel module enabled then you should try dsm($output); just after the view render call. to make sure that it is not an issue with the view.

Comment: @MohammedShameem I've done that already, it prints the view html normally. Anything else I save on $output will load into the myDiv wrapper but the view.

Comment: that is strange. I just tried your code and works fine. It loads the view.

Comment: Can you post the out put of your view as well.

Comment: @MohammedShameem ummm... I think you led me to something, the view that is failing to get built is a OpenLayers view. Now you mentioned that the code worked with you I tried a non OpenLayers view and bingo, it worked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7267/discussion-between-francisco-luz-and-mohammed-shameem)

Comment: In the div wrapper it outputs nothing.

This is the dsm printing https://gist.github.com/4640637

Now that I know the problem lies on the fact that only OpenLayers views fails to get built, I am doing some investigations on that.

Thank you very much for your time @MohammedShameem, appreciated.

Comment: It could be because openlayer depends on js the js is not being called after the ajax load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in OL being addressed by one of its maintainers at
http://drupal.org/node/1895530.

He is in need of help, if you got some savvy skills on Drupal Ajax / JS framework, please check out the post above and, if possible, give him a hand.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE FROM THE QUESTION'S AUTHOR:**
This solution works for non OpenLayers views. It fails to build up the wrapper when the view is an OpenLayers though.

So the question remains to be answered.

---

- You have to create a div wrapper where you are supposed to show the
  ajaxified view content. You have to add the div wrapper in the
  template file (MYTEMPLATE.tpl.php)
- Create a module that will register the ajax link in [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).
  In the callback of the menu item you have to render the view content
  using [ajax_commands](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7).

Sample code:

```
function MYMODULE_init() {
  // Add the Drupal AJAX library.
  // You can optionally provide a check to add AJAX library only on certain pages.
  drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
}

function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['ajax-link/nojs'] = array(
    'title' => 'TITLE',
    'description' => 'DESCRIPTION',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_ajax_link_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => PERMISSION,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  $items['ajax-link/ajax'] = array(
    'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver',
  ) + $items['ajax-link/nojs'];
}

function MYMODULE_ajax_link_callback($ajax) {
  // Check whether this is AJAX callback.
  $is_ajax = $ajax === 'ajax';

  if ($is_ajax) {
    // Your code to obtain view content in HTML format and store it in some variable say $ajax_content.

    $commands = array();

    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('div.WRAPPER-YOU-ADDED-PREVIOUSLY', $ajax_content);

    return array(
      '#type' => 'ajax',
      '#commands' => $commands,
    );

  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message('Content added');
    drupal_goto();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code also works only on non OpenLayers views. It fails to build an OpenLayers view into the wrapper though.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do this on a Drupal 6 site. The problem is that the settings for the view are output in the header as inline javascript, so you can't just load the div containing the view and expect it to work.

What I had to do was use an ajax call to get the page that has the OL view, grab the div from that containing the view html, then grab the inline js from the header of the page, and run that javascript, then run the OL javascript function that initialises the view.

In short it is a massive PIA.

There are some examples of this working on the individual community pages here

http://www.villagesos.org.uk/communities

..though for the life of me I can't remember which one.

Here's the js snippet that does this anyway, you should be able to work out what's going on, but like I say, it's not a great solution and prob worth looking at something other than the OpenLayers module imo.

```
// Load content from a remote url into ajax target
/*
Drupal.behaviors.vsosStateLoader.loadUrl = function(State, target) {
  $.ajax({
    type:State.data.type,
    url:State.data.url,
    data:State.data.data,
    success:function vsosAjaxLoaded(response) {
      // Load the individual elements and Drupal classes into our ajax target region
      var content = $('#main-content > *', response).not('h1, .local-tasks');
      target.find('> .content').html(content);
      // Load any Drupal settings - to set map data
      var settings = $(response).filter('script').not('[src]');
      settings.each(function() {
      //check we have a value
      if($(this).html()){
        var setting = $(this).html();
        //parse out html comments as this breaks in IE
        setting = setting.replace("<!--","");
        setting = setting.replace("-->","");
        eval(setting);
      }
      });
      // Load behaviours onto new content
      Drupal.attachBehaviors();
    }
  });
};*/
```